# go get in Dockerfile. I got cannot find package error

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I added `RUN go get` to install packages during "docker-compose". However, the following `cannot find package` error was occurred when I run `go build`. I found that the packages are saved in `/go/pkg/linux_amd64/`.

**run docker-compose and go build**

```
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker exec -it explorer-cli /bin/bash
# pwd
/go
# ls     
bin  pkg  src
# echo $GOPATH
/go
# ls /go/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/
go-sql-driver
# go build -i -o /go/bin/explorer-cli src/main.go 
src/main.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql (from $GOPATH)

(it worked if I run "go get" manually)
# go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
# ls src/
github.com  main.go
# go build -i -o /go/bin/explorer-cli src/main.go
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: database
    volumes:
      - ./docker/:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./docker/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=explorer
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12dlql*41
  app:
    build: .
    tty: true
    image: explorer-cli:latest
    container_name: explorer-cli
    volumes:
      - ./src:/go/src
    external_links:
      - database
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

ENV GOBIN /go/bin

RUN go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "XUSER:XXXX@(database:3306)/explorer")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

---

Update 1

I noticed big differences between the following directories.

```
# ls /go/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/go-sql-driver/
mysql.a

# ls /go/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/
AUTHORS                 connection_go18_test.go packets.go
CHANGELOG.md            connection_test.go      packets_test.go
CONTRIBUTING.md         const.go                result.go
LICENSE                 driver.go               rows.go
README.md               driver_go18_test.go     statement.go
appengine.go            driver_test.go          statement_test.go
benchmark_go18_test.go  dsn.go                  transaction.go
benchmark_test.go       dsn_test.go             utils.go
buffer.go               errors.go               utils_go17.go
collations.go           errors_test.go          utils_go18.go
connection.go           fields.go               utils_go18_test.go
connection_go18.go      infile.go               utils_test.go
```

---

Update 2

As @aerokite said, the "volumes" was overwriting the downloaded packages. I changed like the followings and it worked.

**Dockerfile**

```
version: '3.4'

FROM golang:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

ENV GOBIN /go/bin

RUN go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql

RUN mkdir /go/src/explorer-cli
```

**docker-compose**

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: database
    volumes:
      - ./docker/:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./docker/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=explorer
      - MYSQL_USER=XUSER
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=XXXX
  app:
    build: .
    tty: true
    image: explorer-cli:latest
    container_name: explorer-cli
    volumes:
      - ./src/explorer-cli:/go/src/explorer-cli
    external_links:
      - database
```

**go build**

```
go build -i -o /go/bin/explorer-cli src/explorer-cli/main.go
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have tried to recreate your problem.

```
FROM golang:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

ENV GOBIN /go/bin

RUN go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

You have provided this Dockerfile. I have build it

```
$ docker build -t test .
```

Now I exec into this image to run your `go build` command.

```
$ docker run -it test bash
```

Then I have created `main.go`, you provided, in `/go/src` directory.

And finally, I have built successfully without any error

```
$ go build -i -o /go/bin/explorer-cli src/main.go
```

And I think I have found your problem. I have never used `docker-compose`. But you will understand.

**Problem** is here:

```
  app:
    build: .
    tty: true
    image: explorer-cli:latest
    container_name: explorer-cli
    volumes:
      - ./src:/go/src  <-- problem is here
    external_links:
      - database
```

You are mounting `./src` into `/go/src` directory in your docker. This process is overwriting directory `/go/src` in your docker with your local `./src`. And this is removing data you got from `go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`

Do you understand?

But when you are running `go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`, its now getting data again.

**Solution (01):**

Mount your local volume into somewhere else.

```
volumes:
  - ./src:/tmp/src
```

And modify your Dockerfile to move this `main.go` to `/go/src`

**Solution (02):**

Copy `main.go` into your docker. Add this line in Dockerfile

```
COPY ./src/main.go /go/src
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it without the volumes as you mentioned.

Comment: Let me know if it wokrs

Comment: You are completely right! That process was overwriting. I'm preparing to post the result. give me 5 min.

Comment: Don't forget to hit necessary button :)