# Go Dep - Missing sub-package "chi/middleware" after dep ensure

Tags: go, go-chi

Missing middleware subpackage from go-chi after running dep ensure.

```sh
project-backend     |  main.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware" in any of:
project-backend     |   /go/src/backend/vendor/github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware (vendor tree)
project-backend     |   /usr/local/go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware (from $GOROOT)
project-backend     |   /go/src/github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware (from $GOPATH)
```

my Docker file, i also mounted my code volume inside my docker-compose.yaml file

```
FROM golang:1.12

WORKDIR /go/src/backend
COPY Gopkg.toml Gopkg.lock ./
RUN go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
COPY . ./
RUN dep ensure

RUN go get github.com/pilu/fresh

CMD [ "fresh" ]
```

Gopkg.toml

```
[prune]
  go-tests = true
  unused-packages = true
  non-go = true

[[constraint]]
  name = "github.com/go-chi/chi"
  version = "4.0.2"
```

my Code, is just a basic router to test my docker and dep configuration.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware"
)

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)

    port := ":8080"

    r.Get("/api", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("API is working!"))
    })

    format := "\033[1;36m%s\033[0m"
    fmt.Printf(format, "Build success, running on port "+port)
    http.ListenAndServe(port, r)
}
```

My code works fine when using go get. But on dep, it's missing its subpackage.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Go 1.12, can you try and see if the issue persists when using [`go mod` (Go 1.11+ Modules)](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules).

```
$ export GO111MODULE=on                         # manually active module mode
$ cd $GOPATH/src/<project path>                 # e.g., cd $GOPATH/src/you/hello
$ go mod init
```

A `go mod init` will concert your dep `Gopkg.lock` file.
And it should detect and fetch your missing dependency.
If that has worked, then run `go mod tidy` to possibly prune any extraneous requirements.

Comment: i think it's a docker issue. I was deleting my docker container and build it again and it works. But deleting my docker container every time i install a go module is frustrating, i'm tweaking my Dockerfile even, added some of your provided answer but it still requires deleting go container,

Comment: @Developer Why not mounting the sources as a volume, as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48498921/6309. Other example: https://www.callicoder.com/docker-golang-image-container-example/

Comment: i already did mount my code into the volume inside my docker-compose file. I'll update my post accordingly.